# Where do I find the CO2 clearance rate for various plants?

Tags: biochemistry, botany, photosynthesis

I'm trying to get enough plants to bring my office from ~1k ppm of CO2 to ~300ppm of CO2. (If I can't get below the ambient 450ppm, that's fine too.) It'd be nice to know before I start buying plants if I can expect to reach that target without, say, having to turn a conference room into a greenhouse.

But I can't easily find a table that lists the rate at which various kinds of plants remove CO2 from the local atmosphere. I'm aware of the [NASA Clean Air Study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_Clean_Air_Study), which looked like it was mostly focused on other pollutants, and Kamal Meattle's [conclusion](https://www.ted.com/talks/kamal_meattle_on_how_to_grow_your_own_fresh_air?language=en) that it takes 4 Areca Palms per person. But I want to know where that number of Areca Palms came from. Or, more importantly, be able to calculate it for other plant varieties. (He might have been optimizing for something different than I would want to.)

So where can I find this information?